# what does "flush 253:0" in iotop file on RHEL

Tags: linux, performance

I have monitor the IO performance on RHEL via IOTOPs, and I find that there is one process named "flush 253:0" which is the most IO operator.

What does this "flush 253:0" mean? I search in google, not very accurate answer, it seems to be the root path of the system.

Answer (score 4):

It's a kernel process that handles flushing dirty pages (that is your io-writes) from the page cache (that is, your actual file system writes are done asynchronously. This process writes the actual bytes to the drives). See also [Cache and TLB Flushing Under Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cachetlb.txt).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you know if try to reduce this value, which can we do optimization? Thanks.